# Image archiving software

Tags: web-apps, images, web-services, archiving, gallery

I'm looking for some software to organise a medium-size collection of images.  I've found a trunk full of photographs and papers belonging to my great-grandfather and I want to digitise them and make them available online for family to access.  Rough requirements are:

- Should present a web interface.  I'm happy with either hosted solutions or hosting my own.
- Hierarchical organisation of images.  The papers in the trunk are in envelopes which are themselves grouped in larger bags/folders and so on, and I'd like to be able to replicate this structure.
- Multiple versions of an image.  There are a number of cases where there are multiple copies of the same photograph.  I'd like to be able to present these as one image with an 'other versions of this image' link.  At a basic level, hierarchical organisation could meet this requirement.
- Different media types.  I'd like to be able to add text versions of documents as well as images of them, and have the software recognise that these are different formats of the same thing.  Again, at a basic level, hierarchical organisation could do this.
- Text notes, preferably formatted.  I'd like to be able to add captions and multiple annotations to each image.
- Access control.  I don't want to make everything in here public (there are various papers related to family financial affairs) but I do want to make it all available for my family to see.
- Automatic generation of thumbnails.
- Comments - allow users to add comments to images.
- Tagging of images and folders.
- Upload API.  I'd ideally like to be able to upload images through an API.

Does anyone have anything to recommend?

If Google Drive had comments and tagging then it'd do at a pinch!

Comment: Did you ever find something?

Comment: Sorry to say, no, I didn't.  I created something myself in the end, based on Django, but it's not really in a fit state to share.